# Does SQL Server require NetBIOS for Named Pipes?

Tags: sql-server, network, protocol

I'm not all that familiar with networking or protocols and couldn't find a similar question here or elsewhere. One of my security people is asking whether SQL Server requires NetBIOS for Named Pipes. I found [this article](https://documentation.help/sql.2005.setupsql9/8a68dd86-0446-4a01-b01d-c52743e13f45.htm) that says NetBIOS should be disabled, but it's rather old and not from a source I've heard of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes

From [this MSDN forum discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/632d47ba-58a1-498d-ad1c-d680dc84b88f/shared-memory-named-pipes-tcp-protocols-how-to-connect-using-each-one?forum=transactsql), Tibor says:

> Named Pipes uses NetBIOS

And from [this MSDN forum discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/edb013a2-a069-4b8d-b1e6-a605fff4f015/disable-windows-netbios?forum=sqldatabaseengine), Puzzle_Chen says:

> Named pipes use the NetBIOS session layer